# Finding geologic trend of unprojected fault line drawn on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, spatial-statistics

Is there anything from the toolbox that can help?

I had fault lines with geographic and projected coordinates and [Linear Directional Mean](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/linear-directional-mean.htm) from the Spatial Statistics tool worked for finding out the compass angle/trend.

However, it does not seem to work for lines without any coordinates attached to it.

I have tried finding help online but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: If you have more information to add to your question, please revise it by using the [edit] button beneath it.  Potential answerers may or may not have time to read comments added to questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a feature class or shapefile with an Undefined Coordinate System then the tool to define one is called [Define Projection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/define-projection.htm):

> This tool overwrites the coordinate system information (map projection
>   and datum) stored with a dataset. The only use for this tool is for
>   datsets that have an unknown or incorrect coordinate system defined.
>
> All geographic datasets have a coordinate system that is used
>   throughout ArcGIS to display, measure, and transform geographic data.
>   If the coordinate system for a dataset is unknown or incorrect, you
>   can use this tool to specify the correct coordinate system. You must
>   know the correct coordinate system of the dataset before using this
>   tool.

Comment: Or maybe the line is a graphics line object and not spatial data?  In that case, add the drawing toolbar to your map, select the line, and use convert graphics to feature to convert the graphics line to spatial data.

Comment: @GBG your comment seems to be a reasonable interpretation of an ambiguous question so I think you should write it up as an answer.